# Copy layer-style(effect) with settings

Tags: copy-paste, effects, photoshop-script

i am writing a script for photoshop and I´m looking for a way to copy a layer-style from one layer to another. The applied layerstyle can vary so I must be able to look for any possible style and copy it. I found some code to copy a layer style but the settings won´t be copied. Using the script listener does not help me much because it´s all hardcoded..

Is there a way to also copy the settings of a style? And a way to do this for all possible styles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is my understanding that Adobe does not have any methods for retrieving styles or style properties in the scripting interface. Apparently though, this can be done manually through Action Manager code. This post in the Adobe forums discuss some of the ways to go about doing that: [How to get the style of a  layer using Photoshop Scripting ?](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/714406)

I Haven't tested this but this maybe what you are looking for:

```
if (app.documents.length > 0 && app.activeDocument.layers.length > 1) {
    transferEffects(app.activeDocument.layers.getByName("styleLayer"), app.activeDocument.activeLayer);
};
// function to copy layer effects of one layer and apply them to another one
function transferEffects(layer1, layer2) {
    app.activeDocument.activeLayer = layer1;
    try {
        var id157 = charIDToTypeID("CpFX");
        executeAction(id157, undefined, DialogModes.ALL);
        app.activeDocument.activeLayer = layer2;
        var id158 = charIDToTypeID("PaFX");
        executeAction(id158, undefined, DialogModes.ALL);
    } catch (e) {
        alert("the layer has no effects");
        app.activeDocument.activeLayer = layer2;
    }
};
```

Comment: thanks that helped me. i also found this  [jamStyles](http://www.tonton-pixel.com/JSON%20Action%20Manager/jsDoc/symbols/jamStyles.html)  Module that is helpful with effects.